# The dot product is a valid kernel. Is the integral too?

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

One of the most well known [kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel) (which in my case is used as a covariance matrix of a Gaussian process) is the dot product kernel $k\left(x, x'\right)= x \cdot x' =\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} x'_{i}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It's symmetric and positive semidefinite, hence a valid kernel.

For an infinite dimensional vector, $y \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$, which I would interpret as a function, not a vector (I'm shaky here), e.g. $y = e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}$, would

$$k(y, y') = y \cdot y' = \sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i y'_i = \int y y' \mathrm{d} r$$

also be a valid kernel? It seems symmetric but I'm not sure it is positive semidefinite and whether my handwavy way of going from the sum to the integral is even vaguely correct.

**EDIT**: I found a "counter example". Negative eigenvalues imply that the kernel is not positive semidefinite (PSD). With a dataset of three data points

$$\vec{y}=(y_1, y_2, y_3)^T
=\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{N}(-1,1.5)+\mathcal{N}(0, 0.1)\\
\mathcal{N}(2,1.5)+\mathcal{N}(3, 0.1)\\
\mathcal{N}(4,1.5)+\mathcal{N}(5, 0.1))
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} \ ,
$$

where $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ denotes a probability density function of the normal distribution,  $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}$, the following gram matrix is generated,

$$
K = \int (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T \cdot (y_1, y_2, y_3)
= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3.43442 & 0.186413 & 0.0680187 \\
 0.186413 & 0.613469 & 0.433659 \\
 0.0680187 & 0.433659 & 0.188063 \\
\end{array}
\right) \ .
$$

(Note, all elements have a tiny imaginary part which I left out for clarity but it doesn't change the result.) For instance, the top left element is calculated as $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \mathcal{N}(-1,1.5)^2 + 2 \mathcal{N}(-1,1.5)\mathcal{N}(0, 0.1)^2 + \mathcal{N}(0, 0.1)^2 dx = 3.43442$. The eigenvalues of this gram matrix, $K$, are 3.44958, 0.869092, and **-0.0827286**. The negative eigenvalue implies that the matrix is not PSD.

I did all this in Mathematica with

```
  Eigenvalues[
  Integrate[
   Table[
     {PDF[NormalDistribution[m, 1.5], x] + 
       PDF[NormalDistribution[m + 1, 0.1], x]}, {m, {-1, 2, 3}}
     ] . {Table[
      PDF[NormalDistribution[m, 1.5], x] + 
       PDF[NormalDistribution[m + 1, 0.1], x], {m, {-1, 2, 3}}
      ]},
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Comment: Is this what you mean by "kernel"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are correct about writing the summation as the integral.
Look here - [Integration with respect to counting measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764076/integration-with-respect-to-counting-measure)

And yes, it is the same as for the dot product kernel because it is the inner product on the [space of sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) $l^2$
$$\sum_i^n\sum_j^nc_ic_j\sum_m^\infty y_{i,m}y_{j,m}=\sum_i^nc_i\sum_m^\infty y_{i,m}(\sum_j^n c_jy_{j,m})=\sum_m^\infty (\sum_i^n c_iy_{i,m})(\sum_j^n c_jy_{j,m})=\sum_m^\infty (\sum_i^n c_iy_{i,m})^2\geq0$$
Because finite and infinite sums (or integrals) can be exchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that the summation can be exchanged for the integration. In the meantime, I found a "counter example" which I edited into the main post. It's a bit clunky but the matrix I get from the data is not PSD due to the fact that some of its eigenvalues are negative. I suppose I did something incorrectly to arrive at this, because it should be impossible. If you could look at it again, I would appreciate it.